# The init method used in this structure is confusing?

Tags: swift, struct, initialization

I'm not understanding why `self.rate = rate` is necessary....isn't `rate` already declared and known that it is a `Double`....the init method supposedly initializes `rate` but its not setting an actual double value to it....so how is `rate` being "Initialized".....also what's the point of using the wildcard (_) before the `rate` parameter?

Also could I have just typed rate = 0.0 rather than using an initializing method? what is the power in using init()?

```
struct MilesPerHour { 

    var rate: Double 

    init(_ rate: Double) { 

        self.rate = rate 

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.rate` is the struct's own property; `rate` (inside the `init` method) is the parameter of the method, so the method initializes the property to the value of the parameter. It might be confusing, but the following method would have the same effect:

```
init(_ rate2: Double) { 
    self.rate = rate2
}
```

As for the underscore, it has no function here. It usually indicates you can skip the parameter name when calling the method, but this is always the case for the first parameter. This is even mentioned in a note in the [documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID526)

> Because the first parameter omits its external parameter name by default, explicitly writing an underscore is extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

if "rate" isn't necessary when you initialize "Miles per Hour" then you don't need to do it this way. You can declare rate like this: 
var rate: Double?

and unwrap it after you know it's been initialized (if rate != nil -> do something with rate!)

Answer (score 0):

self.rate is the struct's own field; rate (inside the init method) is the parameter of the method.
Try not to use 0 or other, the parameter would build up a stack overflow which can be methodic wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When an external name is not needed for an initialize , underscore '_' is used to override the default behavior. And, self.rate is the struct's owned property and the method initializes the property of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> why self.rate = rate is necessary....isn't rate already declared and known that it is a double....the init method supposedly initializes rate but its not setting an actual double value to it....so how is rate being "Initialized"

`rate` is passed to the contructor as a parameter. The parameter value is lost when the constructor is done. We need to assign that value to the instance variable otherwise the value is lost. The fact that the instance variable and parameter have the same name is not a rule but it is very common. `self.` prefix serves to distinguish between the parameter and  the instance variable.

> also whats the point of using the wildcard (_) before the rate parameter?

Swift methods also have an external parameter name which must be specified when calling the method. If you don't want to have an external parameter in constructor, you have to use `_` to ignore it.

> also could I have just typed rate = 0.0 rather than using an initializing method? what is the power in using init()?

Yes, you could do it but the whole point is that the caller of the constructor can specify the value. Initializer is often used to set default values for variables that are constant (cannot be changed after initialization) or they are private. The whole point of an initializer (contructor) is to get the object to a valid default state.